# I am raising an apache and php server with docker, I can enter and view it but other people in my network cannot access the

Tags: php, docker

I am learning docker, and my first step was to create a server with apache and php, and show a simple code; What I did was build my image with my docker file according to the following lines of code:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache 
COPY . /var/www/html
```

My index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
    <?php
        echo '<p>Estoy Ejecutando mi primer contenedor en Docker</p>'
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The container running:

[image]

Entering from my machine:

[image]

But when you try to enter from another machine on my network:

[image]

I raised my server with XAMPP and everything perfect, my network companions can reach you, but lifting it with docker can not.

Proxy is used in my company, and I already set it up but I don't know if that can greatly influence

Attachment captures where the httpd / conf configuration file should be inside the apache by raising, but I don't get it

[image]

Comment: Post your apache config

Comment: How can I find that configuration inside docker?

Comment: Theres a bunch of places it could be, for my own personal apache server its located in `/etc/httpd/conf`

Comment: Update my question, I don't get that directory inside my apache server

Comment: I think that you're running the server locally. If you want to access your docker http on your network, you need to make a NAT on port 80 of your http docker and redirect to port 80 of your public IP. See more on [docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: In your docker file make sure you add `EXPOSE 8080`

Comment: add EXPOSE 8080 to my docker file and it still doesn't work

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes Could you give me more detail on how to do what you tell me, since I read the documentation but did not get configuration information